# How to create a relation N:N and 1:N in the same table?

Tags: sql, database, relation

I have one table to register all my images for example clients logo, users photos and promotions images. The problem is that one promotion might have more than one image. As I use this table for other imagens besides from promotion, I can´t use a foreign key inside it. So my doubt is what to do, create a intermediate table between promotions and images or create a table only for promotions images.

Thank you

Comment: create another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if 1 image can be in many promotions and one promotion can has many images, then create relation **N:N** by 3 tables:

```
image:
imageID INT,
image   YOUR_TYPE_OF_IMAGE,
...


promotion:
promotionID INT,
description VARCHAR(255),
name VARCHAR(255),
...


image_and_promotion:
imageID INT,
promotionID INT
```

You can add check for 3th table:

```
UNIQUE(imageID, promotionID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an intermediate table between promotions and images

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

if an image can only be related to one promotion create a table for the images which has a foreign key to the promotion table. So then each image can be referenced to a promotion.
This would be 1:n

if an image can be related to more than one promotion, you should also create a table for the images but also a table for relation promotion_images.
This would be an n:n relation.